# WPM HttpClient/1.0 which browser it is?

Tags: browser, user-agent

Does anyone have an idea which browser or application specifically sets User-Agent to `WPM HttpClient/1.0`?

```
{
    "name": "User-Agent",
    "valueList": [
        "WPM HttpClient/1.0"
    ]
}
```

Comment: When you google/ixquick/bing/... that user agent, you get the java API commons httpclient. Haven't you ixquicked yet?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a web monitoring solution called [Neustar Web Performance Management](https://home.wpm.neustar.biz/), at least it would fit the `WPM` part of the string.

See their [HttpClient Java class](http://docs.wpm.neustar.biz/testscript-api/biz/neustar/wpm/api/HttpClient.html), which might be used to produce those calls you see.

Comment: yeah I also checked.. but was not sure as Neustar doesnt say anywhere it will set this user-agent, and WPM is common for WebPageMonitoring